# How do I count the number of times a string appears in a text file with only AWK?

Tags: linux, awk

I am writing an AWK script which takes a list of dates and formats it into an easier to read list. I was able to do that no problem.

The real problem is this. After displaying the list, I want to display how many times "2010" appears in the text file.

How do I do this? I've been searching for days and I've come up with absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( $i == "2010" ) count++ } END { print count }' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. After fiddling about with it, it worked. I actually had just about the same thing but I guess I needed to confirm what I was doing was right. It turns out the real problem was where I placed my paranethesis in my script. It all works good now. I was going crazy trying to understand what I was apparently doing "wrong."

Comment: Note that this will count only occurrences of '2010' that awk sees as distinct fields, i.e., delimited by whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F"2010" 'NF>0 { count += NF-1 } END { print 0+count }
```